# What is meant by "doppler extent"?

Tags: radar

A google search of "doppler extent", Where I found the term:

[Extracting Target Features from Angle-Angle and Range-Doppler Images](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/1d64/6a5ebe91f8d546ff3152423b105f1d52dcd4.pdf)

1993 - ‎Cited by 5 - ‎Related articles
**Doppler extents** (as for angle-angle images) by using the estimated target dimensions. Image Scene Analysis. The goal of target feature extraction is to obtain ...

Comment: It probably means the upper and lower doppler frequencies produced by a moving target as detected by a radar type system.

Answer (score 2):

Contrary to popular belief, there is no "secret decoder ring" that gives a single, precise definition for every word or phrase you might find in a technical paper. Just like anyone else, you're going to have to read the paper and decide whether

- it's a standard phrase used in a standard way
- a standard phrase used in a non-standard way
- a phrase the author made up

Sometimes the author will give a clear definition, and sometimes you need to infer a definition from context. Sometimes you need to see whether you can find the phrase in other papers, and then decide whether the two papers are using it in the same way.

Answer (score 1):

As Andy mentioned in the comments the Doppler extent is the range of Doppler frequencies that a target encompasses.

A real target is more than just a point and if it is rotating relative to the radar can cover multiple Doppler bins.

In an airborne radar ground clutter can cover very large extents in doppler all the way from the aircraft velocity to the negative value of the velocity because antenna sidelobes can reach the ground behind the aircraft even when the antenna is pointing forward.